# if (TreeView.Nodes[i] == null) Throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to test, if a node in a c# tree View is null or not. .equals(null) does not work, too. I know, that i can not acces a array, if the [n] is null, but how can i achive that? Using Nodes.Count does not help, too, because the count function counts all child nodes, not only the direct ones.
How do you check, if a Node is non existant?

Best regards.

Comment: Are you sure your TreeView is instantiated, and the nodes are instantiated? It could be throwing a null pointer exception before it even gets to evaluating the index.

Comment: Perhaps showing the code that has the error would help to better understand your scenario

Comment: I just found my error: the nodes.count() function returns the number of child nodes. I accidently did not realize, that a array starts with 0.... if (TreeView.Nodes.Count > i) achives my goal. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

if `TreeView.Nodes[i] == null` throws a NullReferenceException, it is `TreeView` itself that is null.